# How to pass Liquibase 'update' CMD parameter in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cmd, liquibase

We have a `spring-boot`, `liquibase` and `Gradle project`.

In liquibase we can pass [update](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) parameter so that we can update the database and that works fine.

As we are using spring-boot, we want to do it by spring-boot.

But how do I pass this `update` parameter in spring as [there is no such spring-boot property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Why would you need that? Spring Boot has out-of-the-box support for liquibase so no need to mess around with command yourself.